# Code simplification for authorized chars only

Tags: php

I get a string that contains `"@string.number (other stuff)"`.
I want to filter input from start+1 (= ignore the `@`) until I get something different than alphanumeric or `'-', '_', '.'`.

Here's my function:

```
function _isCharAllowed($c)
{
    return (ctype_alnum(str_replace(array('-', '_', '.'), '', $c)));
}
$f=1;
while ($this->_isCharAllowed(mb_substr($str, $f, 1)))
    $f++;
$key=mb_substr($str, 1, $f-2);
```

I want two things. First I have a problem with strings containing `'-', '_', '.'` because it doesn't do want I want: when there's such string, it removes those chars, giving empty string to ctype_alnum() which returns false:

```
php -r 'echo var_export((ctype_alnum("")), true)."\n";'
```

And I would like to optimize it.
How would you do?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the Input and the expected Output !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace them to an allowed character, say `a`. That way the string will never be empty.

Sidenote: I'm horrified (but not surprised) to hear that `ctype_alnum("")` returns `false`. It totally contradicts what the manual says... and the behaviour is even different in some versions: http://3v4l.org/IEtdi

Comment: **`°_°`** You're right. This is just so... messy. Well, it's classical Php: mess, mess, mess.

Comment: I guess they tried to fix it in 5.0 (at least that's how I interpret the changes between versions), but by that time people were relying on the wrong behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [**preg_replace**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Example:

```
$pattern = '/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]/';

$strs = [
'some_string-with234.a',
'ano^ther-st*ring-with´+º~º'
];

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $str) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: So you mean "remove all chars that are not the chars I want"? This way I think I wont know where to stop to be able to do a mb_substr($str, $f, 1))... I need an index to be able to have a substring (the string is far more complex actually)